# Meaning of 'sense' in 'a man of eminent good sense'

Tags: meaning-in-context

I would like to conclude the accurate meaning of ***sense*** in the following phrase.

> a man of eminent good **sense**

That phrase is from one of example expressions in [the entry for the adjective, 'eminent'](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/eminent?q=eminent) in the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary.

I assume the meaning of ***sense*** in that phrase is **judgment**, the 4th of [the definitions defined by the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/sense_1?q=sense) as follows. Why I assumed so is merely because ***eminent good sense*** is an uncountable noun and the 4th definition is the only one which is uncountable.

But meaning-wise, if it were ***a man of an eminent good sense*** or ***a man of eminent good senses***, other definitions can be applied, wouldn't it be?

1. [countable] one of the five powers (sight, hearing, smell, taste and touch) that your body uses to get information about the world around you
2. [countable] a feeling about something important
3. [singular] an understanding about something; an ability to judge something
4. [uncountable] good understanding and judgement; knowledge of what is sensible or practical behaviour
5. senses [plural] a normal state of mind; the ability to think clearly
6. [countable] the meaning that a word or phrase has; a way of understanding something

Comment: Judgment is the correct meaning.  With respect to your second question, you might find *a man **with** an eminent good sense* but you are unlikely to find *a man **of an eminent good sense*** as the latter would not be an idiomatic use.  *A man of impeccable reputation*, yes, but *A man of **an** impeccable reputation*, no.  The complement of **of** there is the quality nominally, in the abstract, not an instance of the quality.

Comment: But even with **with** the indefinite article is not likely when the meaning of *sense*  is "judgment".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Thank you very much for answering. It resolves the problem perfectly. I appreciate it. :) But, if I may ask you a little further from your last comment, is ***a man with eminent good sense*** also as natural and correct as ***a man of eminent good sense*** when **sense** means judgment? And do they mean the same thing and are interchangeable?

Comment: In contemporary American English, the phrase **of eminent good sense** would strike most speakers as rather formal, posh, or literary. The perception is the result of the adjective **eminent**, which is a word you don't hear on the street-corner or in the supermarket, in combination with a prepositional phrase headed by **of** expressing some human *virtue*.  *A stroke of good luck* is normal register, so it's not the structure itself alone. But a person who says *a woman of prodigious talent* or *a man of great discernment* might as well be wearing a monocle :-)

Comment: The preposition **with** reduces that "monocled" effect somewhat.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I greatly thank you for the detailed answer. But can I confirm one thing from your comments to check if I understood you correctly? To sum up your answer for the additional question, whether **of eminent good sense** and **with eminent good sense** have any differences, the only difference is that **of eminent good sense** has more of **monocled effect** than **with eminent good sense**. I am sorry that I responded a little late. I had to take enough time to understand this.

Comment: Yes, the practical meaning is for all intents and purposes the same, and the difference is one of register, although as I mentioned, **with** makes the register only a little less "monocled" because  the word **eminent** is a word  not found in the working vocabulary of the average speaker.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Thank you very much for the answer and help, sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in your understanding of ***sense*** in the example. There's nothing more to be said about that. So I will now address the other part of your question.

If a person is ***of*** something, used to describe a characteristic such as sense, intelligence, stupidity, good looks, and so on, then that characteristic will pretty much always be the characteristic *in the abstract*. It is the characteristic, not an instance of it. Thus, it will always be a mass (uncountable) noun. It can also be used in the plural for things that people actually have several of - "a man of good ideas".

If you were to use ***with*** instead of *of*, then you could use it for characteristics in the abstract (mass nouns) or specific instances (countable nouns). You then use a definite or indefinite article as appropriate by the usual 'rules'.

> A man with **an eminent good sense**.

This could mean someone with one of the "five senses" that are particularly acute, but being so close to a familiar phrase means that people would usually take it the usual way instead. Part of the issue is that "**good sense**" is acting as a noun phrase, which we are used to meaning "sense" in the sense of "judgement". You can make people interpret "good sense" as less of a *set phrase* by making them think of *good* as a separate adjective, by shifting *eminent* to become the adverb form *eminently*:

> A man with **an eminently good sense**.

This says that the level of 'goodness' is such as to make it eminent. However, the "good sense" being there will still make people think of judgement, so it's not going to shift meaning to allow any other sense of *sense*. So let's swap *good* for another word that only applies to the "forms of perception" sense of *sense*:

> A man with **an eminent acute sense**.
>   A man with **an eminently acute sense**.

The first says that the sense, whichever it is, is both eminent and acute. The second says that it is so acute as to be eminent.

Finally, if you make it plural the shades of meaning change again:

> A man with **eminent good senses**.
>   A man with **eminently good senses**.
>   A man with **eminent acute senses**.
>   A man with **eminently acute senses**.

All of these will tend to be taken as something other than "judgement", because that sense of *sense* doesn't become plural. The difference between *eminent* and *eminently* is the same as above.

Comment: Thank you very much for the delicate answer. It is so helpful as for me to see and understand the issue perfectly!